# Opening and Editing CorelDraw Files on MacOS Sierra

Tags: file

I am wondering if anyone knows a reliable way to open CorelDraw files on MacOS Sierra. Apparently, CorelDraw software didn't provide MacOS support for nearly 15 years.

I have tried the free Inkscape, but it didn't work for me. The file would open, but the content was not displayed properly. I am open to other suggestions in form of software.

Perhaps there is a way to reliably convert the files to another format for which there is free alternative for MacOS that can be used to view the contents of the file.

Answer (score 2):

You can check out this free option: [CDRViewer](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/cdrviewer/id600067300?mt=12). It will allow you to open/view CorelDraw files.

For more advanced functionality, the same developers offer [PrintLab Studio 3](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/printlab-studio-3/id1161106531?mt=12).

You can also visit the developer's direct website at: http://blue-tail.com

**NOTE:** I have no affiliation whatsoever with the developer or this product.

**[EDIT]**

Just thought I should add that Adobe Illustrator has always been capable of opening CorelDraw files. I mention this in case you already have access to Illustrator and didn't realise it supported this.

Comment: I have tried their product. It has the same fault as the Inkscape. Multi-page or multi-layer documents do not display correctly.

Comment: Have you tried Adobe Illustrator by any chance? If you can't find a product that meets your needs you may be best to download a trial version of CorelDraw to use on a PC (or within a Windows virtual machine on your Mac) and then export the files into a compatible format such as .ai, .psd, .eps, etc. Or, if you need to keep them in their original format, it may be worth setting up Windows virtual machine or a Boot Camp installation on your Mac and just using CorelDraw within that when you need to. If I hear of any other solutions I'll let you know.

Comment: I will either need to get around to a windows machine or use the virtual machine method. I have these files because the original design was not made by me but i now need to make some tweaks. Is there a reason why one would use CorelDraw? Is it inherently better at something? It appears that being limited to Windows is a serious downside, especially knowing that a lot of designers prefer to work on Macs.